# how to fix space in expandable list view in parent but not in child

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I use an expandable list view. I want to show space between parents but child still same.
I use expandable list view

```
  <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/listviewExpandAble"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></ExpandableListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code:- 

 <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/eventplanning_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:childDivider="@color/child_divider_color"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:divider="@color/child_divider_color"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:scrollIndicators="none"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:transitionGroup="true"/>
```

Comment: how it will work can you tell me. i am a new developer plz

Comment: why we use the color in childDivider

Comment: Add this code in your XML and define the constant "child_divider_color" in your color file inside style

Comment: This is just optional ,if you don't want to use then ignore this line . Exclude this line from the code and run.

Comment: last child and parent below child have no space.

Comment: when i expand the parent the last child attached with next parent . i want last child and next parent hold space

Comment: Please attach the screenshot of your output here. @RanaUmerfarooq